# Laravel returns htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I have the following Laravel 5.1 controller function

```
public function editare($prod_id) {

    $categorii=DB::table('categorii_produse')
        ->select('cat_id')
        ->get();

    $categorie_selectata=DB::table('produse')
        ->leftjoin('categorii_produse','prod_cat_id','=','cat_id')
        ->where('prod_id','=',$prod_id)
        ->select('prod_cat_id')
        ->get();

    $articole=DB::table('produse')
        ->leftjoin('imagini','prod_id','=','img_prod_id')
        ->where('prod_id','=',$prod_id)
        ->get();


    return view ('pagini.editare',compact('categorii','categorie_selectata','articole'));
```

And the following line in the view which has problems

```
{!! Form::select('categorii',$categorii, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

The view returns the following error

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 2nd argument you need to pass array in format `value => displayed option` (in your case I see you only use `cat_id` as both value and displayed option), so instead of:

```
{!! Form::select('categorii',$categorii, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

you should use:

```
{!! Form::select('categorii',collect($categorii)->lists('cat_id')->all(), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: It says **Call to a member function lists() on array** now

Comment: Sorry, I missed you don't use Eloquent here, I fixed the code. If it wouldn't work, try also removing `->all()` method from my code (I cannot test it at the moment)

Comment: Works now ! Thanks for the help